# Can't send messages in Channel through Client credentials provider flow - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send a message in Microsoft Teams Channel via Client credentials provider flow. But it gives the following error.

[image]

I've followed the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

```
POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
```

This is how my API Permissions look like.
[image]

I'm not sure if we can send messages on the channel through the application. Because I don't want to send it via delegated way. Is there any way we can achieve this?

UPDATE:
This is how I'm generating the token.
[image]

Update 2:
screenshot of the postman request.

[image]

Comment: Application permission is supported. 401 error means the access token is incorrect. Please provide the screenshot of how you acquire the access token.

Comment: I've added the screenshot on how i'm generating the token for client_credentials.

Comment: It looks good. Can you share a full screenshot of call `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages`? I mainly want to check how you use the access token.

Comment: It should be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEYn9.png

Comment: You missed `Bearer `. It should be `Bearer {accessToken}`.

Comment: With that also it didn't work :'(

Comment: Please share a newest screenshot, including the request header and error message.

Comment: Here is how I'm generating the token https://i.imgur.com/HdKPUfH.png
Here is the screenshot of the complete postman header request: https://i.imgur.com/fQvWmVi.png
and here's the screenshot of the body: https://i.imgur.com/gWqQkev.png

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224458/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-ali-asad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you missed "Bearer " in **Authorization** header.

[image]

But based on my test, although we add `Group.ReadWrite.All` and `Teamwork.Migrate.All` Application permission, it will still give `401 Unauthorized` error.

After a research, I find that the use case of Application mode is to [Import third-party platform messages to Teams using Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams).

See the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-import-messages-text-only).

I'm afraid that we have to use delegated way to send messages to Teams channel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, I believe I'm also following the same way, I've attached the screenshot in my question above on how I'm generating the token. but still it gives the unauthorized 401 error

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, appreciate it.